# Insert from same table with certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table where I store meta data:

```
id|meta_key|meta_value
========================
 1|gender  |male
 2|gender  |female
 3|gender  |female
 4|gender  |male
 5|gender  |female
```

now I would like to add a salutation based on the `meta_value` so it becomes

```
id|meta_key  |meta_value
========================
 1|gender    |male
 1|salutation|Hello Mr.
 2|gender    |female
 2|salutation|Hello Mrs.
 3|gender    |female
 3|salutation|Hello Msr.
 4|gender    |male
 4|salutation|Hello Mr.
 5|gender    |female
 5|salutation|Hello Mrs.
```

While this could work with some foreach loop I'm searching for a single statement so MySQL can do all the magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54e1a/2/0)**

```
INSERT INTO table_name(id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT
    id,
   'salutation' AS meta_key,
    CASE WHEN meta_value = 'male' THEN 'Hello Mr.'
         ELSE 'Hello Mrs.'
    END AS meta_value
FROM table_name
WHERE meta_key = 'gender';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an insert-select statement with a `case` expression to generate the appropriate salutation:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT id, 
       'salutation', 
       CONCAT('Hello ', CASE meta_value WHEN 'male' THEN 'Mr. ' ELSE 'Mrs. ' END)
FROM   mytable
WHERE  meta_key = 'gender'
```

Note that this query assumes, based on the provided data, that gender can only have one of the two values - `male` and `female`, and can't contain `null`s. If it's more complicated than that, the `case` expression may need to be tweaked slightly.